# struts-layout1.4 throwing no class def found for messageresource.java ,when using with struts2

Tags: struts2, struts

I was using struts-layout,struts-taglib1.3.8.jar, and struts2.application was working fine.
But, as struts2 already has taglibs, so I removed struts-taglib1.3.8.jar and upgraded struts-layout from 1.2 to 1.4 (which says is compatible with struts2). I started getting below exception where I used layout policy.

I decompiled the layout jar.  It contains a class LayoutUtils.java which makes a call

```
 protected static MessageResources messages = MessageResources.getMessageResources("org.apache.struts.taglib.html.LocalStrings");
```

which throws the below exception.

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts/util/MessageResources
>       at fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.util.LayoutUtils.<clinit>(LayoutUtils.java:48)
>       at fr.improve.struts.taglib.layout.PolicyTag.doStartTag(PolicyTag.java:25)
>       at jsp_servlet._common.__appmenu._jspService(__appmenu.java:269)
>       at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:416)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:326)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>       at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:96)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:527)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:447)
>       at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:163)
>       at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:184)
>       at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:80)
>       ... 95 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts.util.MessageResources
>       at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:280)
>       at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:253)
>       at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:56)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
>       at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:177)
>       at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:37)
>       ... 113 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where it says it's compatible with Struts 2.

In any case, on the off-chance it actually *is*, it still depends on Struts 1 classes, e.g.,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>struts</groupId>
  <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

At the very least you'd need to include the Struts 1 core library.

Here's the thing: Struts 2 looks up its message resources in a very different way than Struts 1, exposes values to the view layer in a different way (although they're still accessible via JSP EL), and so on.

It's quite possible I completely missed the Struts 2 compatibility part, though.

Comment: thanks for comment, I mainly needed layout-policy.there is no way i could use struts-layout with struts2 (i dont want to put any dependency from struts 1 or taglib). I created my own tld and tag handler to work as layout and implemented the policy.